# How do I make my HTML Navigation bar longer?

Tags: html, navigationbar

So my problem is that I want a navigation bar for my website but first, it shows weird points on top of the texts, its way to short and covers the text which is supposed to be under the navigation bar.
Now my question is, how do I fix this mess of a code and what is wrong with it that it is to short and shows those points and why the hell does it cover the text/how can I lower the text?

Well I tried to talk to some people who are better at HTML than I but they didn't have time  and I guess I tried to google some stuff and tried to fix it but it didn't quite fix it.

This is my code btw:

```css
li {
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
  li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
  list-style-type: none;
  .active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
  ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: `li { float: left; }` is a red flag. Float is for wrapping text around other content. We're not in the 90s any more, there's no need to use it as a hack like that. We have Flexbox for putting things in a row.